# Ajax program is not running as I expect

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Ajax program is not running as I expect. See the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").keyup(function() {
    for(var i=400;i<421;i++){
        (function(counter){
            counter=String(counter);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "results/result_html.php?usn="+txt+counter+"&resultType="+resultType,
                dataType:"JSON",
                success:function(result){
                    $("#info").hide();
                    $("#result").html(result);              
                    $("#usn").attr("placeholder", "Class USN");
                }
            });
        })(i);
    }
    alert("hai");
});});
```

In this code I want to show the alert after completing all Ajax request which is in that for loop. But when I run this code alert is showing first. I'm new to Ajax please can anyone help me to run as I expected.

Comment: You realise you're making 21 ajax requests? And ajax is `asynchronous` i.e it will continue processing the function without waiting for a result. Might want to look at [jQuery $.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax is Asynchronous which means, it will continue running the code in parallel. The success function is called after the Ajax request is complete. What you can do is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").keyup(function() {
    var loopsToDo = 20, done=0;
    for(var i=400;i<421;i++){
            var counter=String(i);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "results/result_html.php?usn="+txt+counter+"&resultType="+resultType,
                dataType:"JSON",
                success:function(result){
                    $("#info").hide();
                    $("#result").html(result);              
                    $("#usn").attr("placeholder", "Class USN");
                },
                complete : function(){
                    done++;
                    if( done == loopsToDo)
                    {
                        alert("DONE")
                    }
                }
            });
    }

});});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is weird. Why does it go

```
for(var i=400;i<421;i++)
```

Also, the alert will display first before any of the Ajax calls, because ajax is Asynchronous, meaning it runs seperately to the rest of the code. Since you are running 20 Ajax requests, the alert does not wait for all 20 to complete. What you need to do is keep a count of the Ajax calls in your success part and when that equals 20 then display an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Because AJAX calls are asynchronous, it will set up the AJAX call, then continue to execute the script. The 'success' parameter specifies the callback to use once a response is received - which could happen at any time (hence, asynchronous).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").keyup(function() {
        for(var i=400;i<421;i++){
            (function(counter){
                counter=String(counter);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "results/result_html.php?usn="+txt+counter+"&resultType="+resultType,
                    dataType:"JSON",
                    success:function(result){
                        $("#info").hide();
                        $("#result").html(result);              
                        $("#usn").attr("placeholder", "Class USN");
                        alert("hai");
                    }
                });
            })(i);
        }
    });
});
```

That should solve your problems.

Comment: That will alert "hai" 20 times